# How to check whether a 3D point is left or right of a vector

Tags: c++, geometry, directx, directx-11

I am making a pathfinding AI based off a waypoint graph using DirectX. I have a car with a forwards vector to tell me which direction it's facing. The car will always move in the XZ plane, and never change it's Y coordinate. I want to tell the car to turn right if the next waypoint is on it's right, and the opposite for left. This is the current code that I have for the pathfinding function, and what I'm currently doing to check right (which is incorrect)

```
void Car::Pathfinding(XMVECTOR forwards)
{
    int nextNode;
    if(currentNode + 1 > waypoints->size())
        nextNode = 0;
else
    nextNode = currentNode + 1;

    Accelerate();
    if(onRightOf(forwards, waypoints->at(nextNode)))
        TurnLeft();
    else if(onLeftOf(forwards, waypoints->at(nextNode)))
        TurnRight();

        //SquaredDisplacement is just Pythagoras's theorem without sqrt
    if(squaredDisplacement(waypoints->at(nextNode)) < 100)
        currentNode = nextNode;
}
bool Car::onRightOf(XMVECTOR forwards, XMFLOAT3 b)
{
    forwards = XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors(forwards, XMLoadFloat3(&b));
    XMStoreFloat3(&b, forwards);
    if(b.x <= XM_PI / 4) //So it doesn't have to be exact
                         //The onLeftOf has a >= instead of <=
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I'm aware that XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors will always return positive, although it would be stellar if it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let's vector

```
CB = b - CurrentPosition
```

(I don't see a variable for curr. pos. in your code)

then find sign of expression (it is Y-component of vector product, like cross-product)

```
forwards.X * CB.z -forwards.X * CB.X
```

If it is positive, B is left to current path, if negative - to right